# javascript objects not getting assigned correct member value

Tags: javascript

I have 2 JS arrays and I am iterating through both of them to find similar ones.

```
anomalies.forEach(function(anomaly) {

    links.forEach(function(link) {
        if ((link.source.name === anomaly.source) && (link.target.name === anomaly.target)) {
            console.log("anomaly");
            link.type = "anomaly";
            console.log(link);
        } else {
            link.type = "normal";
        }

    });

});

console.log(links);
```

In a case where the value of `link.type` should be `"anomaly"`, still its reflecting to be `"normal"`. 
[image: log from chrome]

Why is it so and what should be done?

Comment: Can not reproduce -> http://jsfiddle.net/z39d8z1z/

Comment: What do the array contents look like? Without seeing that, it's hard to say whether your code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I was an algorithmic mistake. In the provided screenshot `type="normal"` is the current value of the object.

Consider:

```
Loop1
 Loop2
  condition
```

if the condition inside `loop2` is met for the link object then its type value is assigned `"anomaly"`. But when the next iteration of `loop1` occurs, and the condition is not met for the same link object, then the value is assigned `"normal"`. Hence its an algorithmic mistake.

Comment: What about screenshot, where it is _anomaly_ in header but it is _normal_ in body?

Comment: @Regent: the header shows the value at the time when console.log() is called. Whereas the body is the current state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks, like each does not change start value, try that:

```
n = anomalies.length;
k = links.length;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<k; j++){
      if ((links[j].source.name === anomalies[i].source) && (links[j].target.name === anomalies[i].target)) {
        console.log("anomaly");
        links[j].type = "anomaly";
        console.log(links[j]);
      } else {
        links[j].type = "normal";
      }
    }
}
console.log(links);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation:
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You can see that there is 3 arguments can be passed to the callback function
 - element 
 - index
 - array

If you call forEach like this:

```
var x=[1,2,3,4,6];
x.forEach(function(e){
  if(e==3)f=9;
  console.log(e);
})
console.log(x);
```

1
2
9
4
6

[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

The value of the array element will not change because you are changing a buffers value.

But if you use forEach like this:

```
var x=[1,2,3,4,6];
x.forEach(function(e,i,a){
  if(e==3)a[i]=9;
  console.log(a[i]);
})
console.log(x);
```

1
2
9
4
6

[1, 2, 9, 4, 6]

you see that the value changed in the array.